# "This" not working on an input field on focus

Tags: jquery

I have the following code to get me the id of what ever input is in focus:

```
$('#searchColumnFields input').focus(function(){
    thisId = $(this).css('id');
    $(this).css('border-color', '#CCEBFF');
    pos = $(this).position() ;
    $('#searchHelper').html(thisId);
    $('#searchHelper').fadeIn(250).css('left', pos.left-20);
})
```

However, `thisId` keeps coming back null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ it works for me (i think ). not clear on what you want to do.

Comment: Chrome is the browsers I'm using.

Comment: If you're checking on focus, wouldn't there not have been any text entered yet and so the content would be null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you mean

```
    thisId = $(this).prop('id') ;
```

or

```
    thisId = $(this).attr('id');
```

Comment: Too early in the morning for me, thanks lol!

Comment: @imperium2335, hoping not too early for marking as answer.

Answer (score 1):

[.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) never works on `form` fields use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the text

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements
>   such as input, select and textarea.

```
$('input').val()
```

and if you want to retrive other attributes like `id`, `class`, `name` etc .. then use **[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr)**